# How do I clear failed build tasks / stop them from re-running in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have these old build tasks that keep trying to re-run everytime I start up android studio: [Stale `SignaturePadViewKMM` build task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GkfE.png)

Is there a straightforward way to get rid of these?

I was fiddling around with the UI and didn't see an obvious way to do it. I think some combination of clearing gradle caches etc., will work but is there another way?